# TypeScript function that takes an object or an array

Tags: typescript

I am trying write a function that can take an array or an object but running into these conflicts. How do I tell TS specifically not to look for `length` if something is an object or a property `foo` if its an array?

```
interface Stuff {
  list: [] | Obj;
}
interface Obj {
    foo: "bar"
}
function generateSomething(data:Stuff) {
    console.log(data.list.length) // Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Obj'
    console.log(data.list.foo) // Property 'foo' does not exist on type '[]'
}
```

Comment: you can use that variable type is array or string or object with `typeof VARIABLE`

Comment: You can't use your `data` variable until you're 100% certain it's either an array or an object, because otherwise Typescript can't guarantee type saftey.

Comment: You could use `Array.isArray( data.list )` in an if statement to distinguish between the two.

Comment: you can use if (Array.isArray(data.list))  then check length

Comment: Side note: the type `[]` is specifically the *empty* [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types); an array which definitely has length `0`.  Presumably in practice you'd want something more useful like `string[]` (a synonym for `Array<string>`).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to help Typescript understand at runtime which it is.

```js
function generateSomething(data:Stuff) {
    // if ("length" in data.list)
    // if (data.list instanceof Array)
    if (!("foo" in data.list)) {
        console.log(data.list.length);
    } else {
        console.log(data.list.foo);
    }
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4xsg3gKGWQBtgBnMALmQG0BdZAH2QHkAjAKwG58BffUJFiIU7DnkJFkMAPYzqAIjZwoCvvhgYQCMMBkhkAcwghocSKhkBbCGAAWoQwAoAJubiV0WGAEoJU5AB6QORgHCcFYhNDewVQgzcwOAA6UgofSSJg0PDElLSweIo4bQgZHABBKCg4AE8MgLDkJwBCCNkZONBkPNTyMB8-AgCAhH0yGSjUmWdegtTo+x8eAN5kCGIyFGGRojGQCaniGdd3PopkjuXM5H5eIA)

As Ganesh pointed out in the comments, `Array.isArray(data.list)` works too.